# svg images cause xml error in android studio3.0

Tags: android

I have updated my android studio to 2.3 to 3.0.But the svg images cause crash in my app.I have used the gradle version 4.1.Is there any issue in my gradle version?

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at [this](https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/02/android-studio-svg.html) link. You should use Vector Asset Studio to import vector graphics, you cannot use svg's directly. Official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html#about).

Alternatively, you can convert your svg's using [this](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/) tool.